# media definitions require block statements after any features

Tags: css, compiler-errors, less, media-queries

I have the following code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {

nav a { font-size: 24px; border: 2px dashed @lightColor1; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; float: left; }

nav { line-height: 1.3em; list-style: none; margin: 0; text-align: center; }

nav li { display: inline; padding: 140px; }

nav ul { text-align: center; }

body { font-size: 1.1em; }

h1 { font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 600; }

h2 { font-size: .9em; border-bottom: 5px dashed @lightColor1; }

footer { font-size: .8em; }
}
```

It is displaying "line 190: media definitions require block statements after any features", which is referring to the last line of the code.

This style of code has worked in the past, I am not sure what it is asking me to do?

Comment: Your code is vaild.

Comment: @3rdthemagical it seems that Brackets had an error.. however, if I typed it in again, it went through. Thanks for commenting!